# Button displayed in a different position on Firefox

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, margin

i am working on this website http://steam-to-rent.ch/mietdampfanlagen2.html

If you click on the collapse button you can see a button called "Drucken" (see attachment) that i'm using for print a specific div. As you can see from the screenshot the in Chrome e Safari is ok but not in Firefox. Looks like the bottom margin is not displayed. How can i solve?

[image]

Comment: because you are floating the button to the right...you should clear it. That is not a good practice. use a container (div) around the button, and set `display:block; text-align: right;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use clear both properties for table and then it will be fixed in all browser.

```
clear:both;
```

Comment: What a shame. Thanks :)